# Deep learning based physics engine

Tags: deep-learning

Ridgid body simulation is a well known field with well established methods. It's still fairly computationally expensive to simulate things.

I am interested in approaches to training deep learning networks to predict rigid body dynamics and interactions to reduce the computational load associated with simulations.

Has this been done before and what approaches have been used?

Comment: I think such an engine will need to be LSTM based since states naturally depend on prior states

Comment: 2 minute papers: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbfYPyITQ-7l4upoX8nvctg Does a huge amount of videos specifically on this exact topic. You'll find many many papers on his channel that discuss what you're asking.

Comment: @Recessive You may want to provide a formal answer, if you have the time, based on the information in that video/channel ;)